# General GUI Development: Acceptable tooltip string length?

Tags: gui-design, tooltips

I'm putting the finishing touches on a GUIDE (MATLAB) developed GUI. I wanted to add tooltip strings to help the user but I don't want to overwhelm the user. Here are some examples of tootip strings that I have so far:

These are tooltip strings for 4 radio buttons that I have in a radio-group panel.

> Apply annotation to highlighted region of the selected electrode pair
>
> Apply annotation to entire data range of selected electrode pair
>
> Apply annotation to entire data-set of selected lead (6 electrode
> pairs)
>
> Apply annotation to entire data-set for both leads (12 electrode
> pairs)

This is the tooltip string for a toolbar push button

> Press to start annotating. Depending on selected mode, a highlight
> tool or window will appear

Are these too long or are they an acceptable length? Currently they convey all the information that I need to convey to the user. If these are too long, what could I do to shorten them?

Bonus question: Is there a general short-hand that is used for these types of user "hints" or "tips"? [image]

Comment: Be sure you are using tooltips for the right reason. All-to-often they are used out of habit rather than a real need. As for what is an acceptable length, it's "long enough to actually communicate what you need to communicate but no longer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as length goes, they should be as short as possible and they should be understandable by whatever your user base is. So the length also depends on your user base because you may need to add more or less of an explanation depending on your users.

Also, as [DA01 said](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/83335/general-gui-development-acceptable-tooltip-string-length/83353#comment131532_83335), you should make sure that your UI actually *needs* them, rather than needlessly cluttering your interface with them. Sometimes users will rest their mouse on a part of the screen to think, and that could activate tooltips and bother them. So only use them when necessary.